# Inherit column height from another column in table

Tags: html, css, html-table

Hopefully someone can help with a problem I'm having. I am trying to create a table with 3 columns.

- The LEFT TD is a logo.
- The Middle TD is text, and I want this cell to resize itself (as it would normally) based on whatever text is in there, so I cannot set a defined height for this cell as the content will be different for each row.
- The RIGHT TD has a `div` inside, and the `div` is set to scroll, with a height of 100% of the TD.
  I will have multiple rows in the table, in the example below I have just one for "project management", however I will have other rows too describing other job titles.

I would like the RIGHT TD to inherit the height of the MIDDLE TD, so that no matter what I put in the middle cell, the right hand column will be that height and therefore the `div` will also be that height. Anything inside that `div` which stretches beyond this height will scroll.

Limitations: I am using a content management system Wiki thing which will NOT permit any STYLE tags (will only allow only in-line), and no  or inline scripts such as `onload="dothis()"`. I've looked in existing questions and no answers seem to match my requirements.

Code attempted:

```html
<table dir="ltr" style="width: 950px; border: 0px;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 75px;">&nbsp;</td>
      <td style="width: 575px; text-align: left;">Project Management</td>
      <td><strong>here are some names to contact:</strong>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 75px; text-align: center; vertical-align: center;">LOGO</td>
      <td style="width: 575px; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;">
        <p dir="ltr">Project Management</p>
        <p dir="ltr">a project manager will do many things, including:</p>
        <p dir="ltr">this</p>
        <p dir="ltr">that</p>
        <p dir="ltr">and</p>
        <p dir="ltr">the other</p>
        <p dir="ltr">and don't forget this</p>
        <p dir="ltr">last but not least ,they'll also do:</p>
        <p dir="ltr">this as well</p>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 300px; text-align;left;vertical;align: top;;">
        <div style="height: 100%; overflow-y: scroll;">testing
          <br />testing
          <br />testing
          <br />testing
          <br />testing
          <br />testing
          <br />testing

          <br />testing
          <br />testing
          <br />testing
          <br />testing
          <br />testing

          <br />testing
          <br />testing
          <br />testing
          <br />testing
          <br />testing

          <br />testing
          <BR>oh look at meee I'm not resizing</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Don't use tables for general page layout,,,only for actual tabular data. It's not the 1990's

Comment: HI Paulie_D, thanks for your comment. Please could you suggest an alternative which would achieve the same result? Open to all ideas

Answer (score 0):

You should DEFINETELY not use tables for layout. Use semantic HTML. 
To display the contents beneath each other you can use floating divs.
Also you should remove inline CSS and use a stylesheet file.
Take a look at this example here:

```
<style>
    .content {
          overflow: hidden;
    }

    .box {
          box-sizing: border-box;
          width: 45%;
          padding: 2.5%;
          float: left;
    }
    .box.logo {
          width: 10%;
    }
</style>
<div class="content">
<div class="box logo">
  LOGO
</div>

<div class="box">
  <p dir="ltr">Project Management</p>
  <p dir="ltr">a project manager will do many things, including:</p>
  <p dir="ltr">this</p>
  <p dir="ltr">that</p>
  <p dir="ltr">and</p>
  <p dir="ltr">the other</p>
  <p dir="ltr">and don't forget this</p>
  <p dir="ltr">last but not least ,they'll also do:</p>
  <p dir="ltr">this as well</p>
</div>

<div class="box">
  Project Management<br />
  <strong>here are some names to contact:</strong>
  <div style="height: 300px; overflow-y: scroll;">testing
    <br />testing
    <br />testing
    <br />testing
    <br />testing
    <br />testing
    <br />testing

    <br />testing
    <br />testing
    <br />testing
    <br />testing
    <br />testing

    <br />testing
    <br />testing
    <br />testing
    <br />testing
    <br />testing

    <br />testing
    <br />oh look at meee I'm not resizing</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Simon, unfortunately - 

Limitations: I am using a content management system Wiki thing which will NOT permit any STYLE tags (will only allow only in-line, i.e. ), and no or inline scripts such as onload="dothis()". I've looked in existing questions and no answers seem to match my requirements.

Comment: I also cannot specify the height of the div or the cell, as this needs to be determined by content of the prior column

Comment: but you can use divs instead of table markup? then use my styles inline

Comment: Thanks Simon, this is a great suggestion, I've had a play with it and the only issue I'm having is that I don't want to specify any heights - is there a way that, depending on the content in the first "BOX", the second "BOX" will automatically be the same height, and anything larger will scroll? The reason I don't want to specify any heights is because the first BOX will have a different amount of content in each one.

For example, if the first BOX has 5 lines in it, I want the whole row just to be 5 lines, and I want the second BOX to be 5 lines high with a scrollbar to display anything mo

Comment: There is no clean way to do that. If you could use javascript it would be easy to set the wrapping div (content) height to the first box height.